# parent-child properties value inheritance at runtime/instance

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, domain-driven-design

I have 2 entities with a parent-child relation (like a base product and product variants), basically the two entities have the same properties and at runtime (when instantiating the object) if the the property X have a value in the parent then the same property X should have the same value for the child entity instance.

I try to emulate this behavior by having a property 'parent' in the child entity. Not a mere pointer to the parent but the complete parent object instance, so I can decide from the child perspective if a given property should take the parent (accessible through the parent property) value or have its value "override" ...

I post here to know if there is a better way (pattern ?) to achieve this ? because I feel like instantiating the full parent object inside the child is not the best way to do it but I can't think of a better/simpler alternative ....

in pseudo code :

```
parent = new ProductBase(name:="abc123")
child = new ProductVariant(parent:=parent)
child->getName() // returns the value from the parent ("abc123") because it has noit been overwritten inside child instance
child->setName("def456")
child->getName() // returns the overridded value i.e. "def3456"
```

Thanks for your help/suggestions !

Comment: It sounds like you have a typical inheritance relation, not a parent-child relation.

Comment: but it's an inheritance of values (at instantiation) not just what kind of property is in the object

Comment: It's hard to say when you think you have a composition of entities when you (really) might have an inheritance. It's not clear to me. Could you illustrate with snippets? (_It can be in any language or pseudo-code_). I have a hard time understanding what you have implemented so far.

Comment: Do the objects differ in any way by their shape or behaviour (i.e. different fields with different names and different datatypes or perhaps different methods and implementations), or do they have identical shape & behaviour which merely differ by the *values* written into some of those fields?   (i.e. different records rather than different kinds of objects)

Comment: The objects have the same shape, they only differ by values.
e.g. the parent object have a field "name" with the value "xyZ123", when I access one of the child of this parent I want to be able to implement the following business logic : when accessing the name, retrieve the parent name if it's empty in the child name field (null) otherwise get the override "name" value set in the child instance...

Comment: So, if you ever do `child->setName(null)`,  the response of `child->getName()` is `abc123`? And Is it this way for every common attribute between "parent" and "child"? If yes, then you have a very common "wrapper" or "decorator".

Comment: Yes indeed, so you think the best pattern to use in this case is a decorator ?
As a sidenote, I try to stick to DDD principles so I don't want to couple my business code to some dependency container (from an infrastruxture layer)

Comment: Patterns don't belong to frameworks. Frameworks implement patterns and offer "ports" for you to implement your "adapters" and integrate your code with the framework. It's all up to you if you introduce FWK-specific dependencies in your domain or not. The best way to avoid this is by coding your domain as a standalone module with no other dependency than the SDK and utility libs. As for the "best pattern". Stop thinking in terms of"best/worse". Start thinking in terms of adequacy or simplicity or readability. Solve the problem first. Improve (if necessary) later. –

Comment: BTW: "instantiating the full parent object inside the child" - while implementation details vary across languages, this is effectively *exactly* what happens when you inherit from a class. Now, in your particular case, there might be good reasons to not use inheritance, but, I just wanted to clear that up.